# Confirm Form Resubmission (duplicated, but I can't solve it)

Tags: php, html, post

I have **Test.php**:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['input'])){
    $c=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','controlo');
    $input=$_POST['input'];
    mysqli_query($c,"insert into`vsv 1`(`Nome`)values('$input')");
}
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action=Test.php method=post>
            <input name=input>
            <input type=submit>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works but I get the message "Confirm Form Resubmission" on refresh.
There's a lot of answers out there but I still didn't figure it out how to prevent that from happening.

**EDIT (solution):**

Somehow I was getting something wrong, but aparrently this actually worked:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['input'])){
    $c=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','controlo');
    $input=$_POST['input'];
    mysqli_query($c,"insert into`vsv 1`(`Nome`)values('$input')");
    header("Location:Test.php");
}
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action=Test.php method=post>
            <input name=input>
            <input type=submit>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried replace `method=post` by `method=get` and  `$_POST['input'] `  by `$_GET['input'] `.

Comment: @DanielLagiň - That way, everytime I refresh it sends the submit again. It also changes the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect to any other page or at same page

```
header("Location:page.php");
```

Comment: Do I add that after the `mysqli_query`?

Comment: I added `unset($_POST);` after `mysqli_query($c,"insert into`vsv 1`(`Nome`)values('$input')");` and it's still the same way. I open the page, submit a value, refresh and it appears.

Comment: @user7431066 did you try `header("Location:page.php");` after your `mysqli_query`

Comment: Weird, I'm sure I just did the same thing as before.

Comment: @user7431066 There might be any step which you missed.

Answer (score 0):

The browser says 'Confirm Form Resubmission', because you have submitted form on the previous page.
What you want is click the address bar and hit enter to properly refresh the page.

Comment: But isn't there a trick to make it not appear on refresh, back, forward?

Comment: Yes, just before you close the if($_POST), add redirect to the same page, search in google how you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers automatically warn users about the Form Resubmission when POST-data has been sent. To "fix" this, you have to redirect the user to maybe even the same page using the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)-function.

```
header("Location: your.php");
```